# How do I make a script that sends in a channel after 5 minutes automaticallY?

Tags: discord.js

> **So this is my script and I am looking for a script that sends a message in a channel every 5 minutes. In this case the message is "Welcome"**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'Welcome') {
```

Answer (score 0):

First I am assuming you are using Discord.js v12. Store the channel ID, for example
`const channelID = "1234567890"`
then get the channel object,
`const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId)`
now to send the message

```js
setInterval(async function(){
     channel.send("Welcome")
}, 300000)
```

inside of your `client.on` block